# Ubuntu server doesn't get IP at all

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu server on a laptop and when it boots it doesn't get IP, but when I run Sudo dhclient it gets IP does anyone know how to fix this

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing dhcpcd5

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  In 2 days, you will be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark, which will indicate that the problem was solved.  For readers with a similar problem, this would be more helpful if you can elaborate on it a little.  e.g., what led you to that solution?  How does the reader find and install it?  What does dhcpcd5 do that fixes the problem?  Posts that educate are more valuable.